# lwc testing TypeError: element.wireRecord is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am trying to do a test when no records are returned. Error is here: element.wireRecord(wireRecord);

test code is:

```
it('Check no quote found error', () => {
    const element = createElement('c-bid-summary', {
        is: BidSummary
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    const errorEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3.error');

    const wireRecord = {
        error: new Error('No Primary Quote found for the Opportunity')
    };

    element.wireRecord(wireRecord);

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        expect(errorEl.textContent).toBe('No Primary Quote found for the Opportunity');
    });
});
```

js is:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import retrieveQuoteData from "@salesforce/apex/getPrimaryQuoteBidSummaryLWC.retrieveQuoteData";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
export default class bidSummary extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track records;
    @track dataNotFound;

    @wire(retrieveQuoteData, { keySearch: "$recordId" })
    wireRecord({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            this.dataNotFound = '';
            if (this.records === '') {
                this.dataNotFound = 'No Primary Quote found for the Opportunity';
            }
        } else {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the wire handler directly, but instead use the emit function on the Apex method:

```
// test.js file
import retrieveQuoteData from "@salesforce/apex/getPrimaryQuoteBidSummaryLWC.retrieveQuoteData";
```

...

```
const wireRecord = {
    error: new Error('No Primary Quote found for the Opportunity')
};
retrieveQuoteData.emit(wireRecord);
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_wire_utility).